# What's the ideal method for redirecting to a new url from inside of a View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So inside my ASP.NET MVC View I have a conditional statement to redirect users to a different page.

What is the best way to do this?

What is the `Controller.RedirectToAction()` equivalent for a View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a perversion of MVC and if you can't do the redirect in the controller, then your logic is not correct.

However, here is what I would use if I didn't have access to the controller for whatever reason:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content='0;url=<%=Html.Action("MyAction","MyController") %>'>
```

**Update**

In your comment, you mentioned it's because you're doing role checking and you don't want to do this in every controller/action. If that's the case, then here is something that you might like to consider:

Create a base controller class and have every controller extend from this class.

In your base controller, have an [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) method. In here, you have something like this:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
     if (/*the user is not in the role desired*/)
     {
       RedirectToRoute(filterContext, new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction"});
    }
  }

  private void RedirectToRoute(ActionExecutingContext context, object routeValues)
  {
    var rc = new RequestContext(context.HttpContext, context.RouteData);
    string url = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(rc, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues)).VirtualPath;
    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: it's a role checking thing and I don't want to code it into every single action when I can just do it in my master page and be done with it

Comment: Okay. Well, I've updated the meta tag which to display a Html.Action. This should do everything you need it to.

Comment: I've updated the comment again to reflect your needs. This would a better solution, but as mentioned by TimGThomas, actionfilters are also a good idea/better than mine.

Comment: @Ryan Putting logic in your view is a perversion of MVC, as the answerer said.

Comment: ugh you guys are right, I just realized in testing that I can hit the STOP button on my browser before the redirect happens... guess I have to do it the hard way :)

Comment: I'd go custom ActionFilter all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would likely be to move the conditional to your Controller and perform the redirection there (this also makes the redirection logic easy to test).  Alternatively, you could wrap a JavaScript statement with your View's server-side conditional like so:

```
<% if (viewShouldRedirect) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "/Your/New/Url";
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Yes, this would work. Although if the user has JS disabled (NoScript or wotnot), then this wouldn't work.

Comment: +1 for moving the logic to the controller.  No reason to even render the view to the browser if you are just going to redirect.

Comment: Yeah JS won't fly because if they don't have it then they can still get in, the idea is role checking inside of my Master page... if I do it elsewhere I will have to code into each Action... and remember to do it in all of them from here on out, was hoping for a silver bullet by putting the check/redirect into the master page.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect use for an ActionFilter, then.  You can decorate all your Actions with it and it can automatically redirect if necessary.

Comment: Have you checked out the Authorize attribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Comment: yeah but the users ARE Authorize by the time they get there, just need to prevent the ones with the lower Roles from getting in

Comment: @Ryan.   If you're preventing users from accessing that page, than they are NOT Authorized.  They may be authenticated, but that's not the same as authorization.